# Linked list implementation in cpp

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need some review for this CPP Linked list implementation.
This is my first time implementing such a data structure in CPP.
Thanks in advance.

```
 /* 
 **
 **   author:  Omar_Hafez
 **   created: 12/05/2022  05:15:38 PM
 **
 */
     
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
struct Node {
  Node<T> *next;
  T data;
};

template<class T>
class Linked_List {
  private:

    Node<T> *head = NULL;
    int count = 0;

  public:

    bool is_empty() {
      return (head == NULL);
    }

    void push_front(T value) {
      Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>;
      new_node -> data = value;
      new_node -> next = head;
      head = new_node;
      count++;
    }

    void push_back(T value) {
      Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>;
      new_node -> data = value;
      new_node -> next = NULL;
      if(is_empty()) head = new_node;
      else {
        Node<T> *tmp = head;
        while(tmp -> next != NULL) {
          tmp = tmp -> next;
        }        
        tmp -> next = new_node;
      }
      count++;
    }

    int push_after(T value, T after) {
      if(is_empty()) return 0;
      Node<T> *tmp = head;
      while(tmp != NULL && (tmp -> data) != after) {
        tmp = tmp -> next;
      }
      if(tmp == NULL) return -1;
      Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>;
      new_node -> data = value;
      new_node -> next = tmp -> next;
      tmp -> next = new_node;
      count++;
      return 1;
    }

    int delete_front() {
      if(is_empty()) return 0;
      if(count == 1) {
        count--;
        head = NULL;
        return 1;
      }
      head = head -> next;
      count--;
      return 1;
    }

    int delete_back() {
      if(is_empty()) return 0;
      if(count == 1) {
        count--;
        head = NULL;
        return 1;
      }
      Node<T> *tmp = head;
      while(tmp -> next -> next != NULL) tmp = tmp -> next;
      tmp -> next = NULL;
      count--;
      return 1;
    }

    int erase(int value) {
      if(is_empty()) return 0;
      int cnt = 0;
      while(!is_empty() && head -> data == value) {
        cnt++;
        delete_front();
      }
      Node<T> *tmp = head;
      while(tmp -> next != NULL) {
        if(tmp -> next -> data == value) {
          tmp -> next = tmp -> next -> next;
          cnt++;
          count--;
        } 
        else 
          tmp = tmp -> next;
      }
      if(tmp -> data == value) {
        delete_back();
        cnt++;
      }
      return cnt;
    }

    void print_values() {
      Node<T> *tmp = head;
      while(tmp != NULL) {
        cout << (tmp -> data) << " ";
        tmp = tmp -> next;
      }
      cout << endl;
    }

    int search(T value) {
      Node<T> *tmp = head;
      while(tmp != NULL) {
        if(tmp -> data == value) return value;
        tmp = tmp -> next;
      }
      return -1;
    }

    int size() {
      return count;
    }
};
```

Comment: I was beaten by @Martin York. Anyways, your search function is faulty, in that it's returning `T` instead of `int`. You might want to add `int index` on your code then return that instead!

Comment: I got that. I forget that It is `T`, not `int` so I will fix it to return `T`.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some minor addition: You might consider adding a tail attribute to the Linked List class so that you don't have to traverse the whole list for *_back() methods..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Overview

This is a singly linked list. Which is fine. But it is relatively trivial to implement a doubly linked list (next/prev link in each node). Also by using a doubly linked list and a sentinel (look up the sentinel pattern) you can remove the need to check for `nullptr` (which makes the code easier to read).

You don't release the memory you allocate with `new`. For every call to `new` there should be an matching call to `delete`. This means your object should have a destructor.

You don't obey the [rule of three or five](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/14065).

If your object owns (owns ⇒ creates and destroys) a resource (in this case head) then the compiler-implemented copy constructor and assignment operator will not work (as you expect) and you need to implement your own.

### Code-Review

Always good.

```
/* 
 **
 **   author:  Omar_Hafez
 **   created: 12/05/2022  05:15:38 PM
 **
 */
```

Not sure if you need a time :-) but you may want to add `(C) 2022` if this is auto generated. Note: By posting on this site you are licensing under CC (see bottom of page for details).

---

Never do:

This:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

That include is non-standard and your code is going to break and not compile at some point.

Or this:

```
using namespace std;
```

This is going to get you in trouble in the long run. You should read the article [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065) [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/14065) is the best in my opinion.

Rather than doing this, prefix standard library types objects with `std::`. It's only 5 characters and the name `std` was designed to be short for that reason.

---

This is good. But nobody should use this information (it is an internal detail to the class `Linked_List`) so make it a private member of the class so only it can use it.

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
  Node<T> *next;
  T data;
};
```

---

It's not wrong.

```
    Node<T> *head = NULL;
```

But in C++ (unlike C) the `*` is usually placed as part of the type.

```
    Node<T>*   head = nullptr;
```

In C++ the type information is very important so keeping it all together is useful in reading.

Also `NULL` is C code. In C++ we use `nullptr` - it is type safe (unlike `NULL`).

---

We can simplify this a bit and make it more readable in one go:

```
    void push_front(T value) {
      Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>;
      new_node -> data = value;          // Normally we don't add space
      new_node -> next = head;           // around the -> operator.
      head = new_node;
      count++;
    }

    // How about this?

    void push_front(T value) {
      head = new Node<T>{head, value};
      ++count;
    }
```

This is a OK when `T` is a simple type like `int`. But what happens when `T` is `LargeObjectWithState` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

```
   void push_front(T value)
                   ^^^^^^^
```

You are passing the parameter by value. That means there is a copy made before the call is even made (to copy it to the location where parameters are stored). Then inside the function you are copying into a `Node` object.

```
     new_node -> data = value;   // Makes another copy of the object.
```

To get around this we normally pass parameters by reference to avoid the first copy.

```
   void push_front(T const& value)
                     ^^^^^^          // a reference to the original value.
                                     // but we can't change the value.
```

So that gets around one copy. But C++11 added a concept called *move semantics* that allows us to move objects (rather than copy them). Parameters that are movable are marked with `&&` to indicate that we want to bind to an R-Value reference and that we may steal the content of the object as a result of calling the function.

```
   void push_front(T&& value)
```

There is some magic you have to do. When you assign these values you need to make sure you do so in a way that tells the destination that you are moving the object to the destination:

```
    // Your function would look like this:
    void push_front(T&& value) {
      Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>;
      new_node->data = std::move(value);
      new_node->next = head;
      head = new_node;
      count++;
    }

    // or how about this?

    void push_front(T&& value) {
      head = new Node<T>{head, std::move(value)};
      ++count;
    }
```

Node. You should have both versions of the function:

```
    void push_front(T&& value);
    void push_front(T const& value);
```

There is a third variant called emplacing (but we can get to that in a subsequent review).

---

Basically the same comments for `push_back()` as `push_front()`.

```
    void push_back(T value) {
```

---

Here is returning magic numbers?

```
    int push_after(T value, T after) {
```

- 0: Empty List
- -1: Value does not exist
- 1: Value was inserted.

Not sure why 0 and -1 are different (in both cases `after` does not exist in the list). So it you combine these two you could return a boolean value to indicate whether the value was inserted.

If you must stick with three then I would create an enum that makes this relationship readable.

```
    enum InsertStatus {FailedEmptyList, FailedValueDoesNotExist, OK};
    InsertStatus push_after(T value, T after) {
```

---

This looks very similar to some of the code above.

```
      Node<T> *new_node = new Node<T>;
      new_node -> data = value;
      new_node -> next = tmp -> next;
      tmp -> next = new_node;
      count++;
```

We now have three places where you are calling `new Node` and then setting up the values and incrementing count. When you have repeated code you may want to put that in a named function, so that if there is a bug you only have to fix it in one place - and it makes reading the code easier.

---

If you removed this `if code`.

```
      if(count == 1) {
        count--;
        head = NULL;
        return 1;
      }
      head = head -> next;
      count--;
```

Would it change the behaviour? If there is only one item, then `head->next` should be `nullptr`. So `head = head->next;` would set head to `nullptr`.

My main issue with this function is that you are leaking the `Node`. You allocated that node with `new`, so you should release the memory with `delete`.

```
      Node* old = head;
      head = head -> next;

      delete old;           // every call to new should be matched with a call to delete.
```

---

Don't think this will ever be true.

```
       if(tmp -> data == value) {
        delete_back();
        cnt++;
      }
```

You covered this situation in your main loop above.

---

You don't want to use `std::endl`. It prints `\n` then flushes the stream.

```
      cout << endl;
```

The stream is flushed automatically. You flushing it manually is only going to make it very inefficient.

---

If a function does not change the state of the object, mark it constant.

```
    int size() const 
    {       // ^^^^^^    
      return count;
    }
```

Comment: What a GREAT review! Thanks alot.

Comment: Rather than overloading functions for const-lvalue and rvalue operands, I usually recommend passing by value when we're going to move-from.  This simplifies implementation and prevents combinatorial explosion of function signatures (very important for constructors).  Yes, it means copy+move, but if there's a type where that move is significant compared to allocating our Node, then we want to be looking to improve that type's move constructor rather than complicating our container.

Comment: @TobySpeight is correct (I keep forgetting this simplification of the interface).